# Retrieve single result with 2 columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Do we have any function in oracle do this scenario.

There are 2 columns in table col1, col2.

```
col1 either has 'Y' or 'N' or NULL

col2 eitehr has 'Y' or 'N' or NULL
```

But always only one of the column has value 'Y'.

So , i want to check first col1 whether it has 'Y' ,if it has i want a string "COL1 found" ,if col2 has 'Y' i want a string "COL2 found". Is it possible with NVL2 and Decode function. With one column ,i can able to do that. But here i have to check 2 columns .Please note that i want a result in single row.

Regards,

Chaitu

Comment: if always one of them is 'Y', then you can do decode(col1, 'Y', 'col1 found', 'col2 found')

Comment: But still i want to check col2 also,because some times there may be both have null or N values .

Comment: What should be the result for both 'N' or one 'N' and the other null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select case when col1 = 'Y' then 'Col1 found' when col2 = 'Y' then 'Col2 found' end f
from yourtable
```

UPD.

```
select decode (col1, 'Y', 'col1 found', decode(col2, 'Y', 'col2 found')) from yourtable
```